Event triggers to style another component
I am creating some custom components for a project that I am working on, and I've run into an issue that I am having with styling a user component (I know it's a bit messy, I was planning on cleaning it up after I got it working).
It is a Textbox that has a clear button in it, with a rectangle as its background to have a more seamless look than individually styling the other two components, and I have a hover animation and colour change that I would like to apply when hovering over the UserControl that works for just the rectangle, but I am having a hard time getting it to apply the style to the rectangle when the mouse enters the Textbox and the button. I'm not sure if this is even the right approach (working code and styles below).
ClearableTextBox.xaml
<UserControl x:Class="TestEnv.View.CustomControls.ClearableTextBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestEnv.View.CustomControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="40" d:DesignWidth="250">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ClearableTextBoxDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>


    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textInput" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="35"   
             TextChanged="textInput_TextChanged" Margin="0,2,40,0" MouseEnter="textInput_MouseEnter"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbPlaceHolder" Text="{Binding PlaceHolder}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Light"
               Margin="13,0,30,3" Panel.ZIndex="-1" Height="20"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Panel.ZIndex="-2"/>

        <Button x:Name="buttonClear" Click="buttonClear_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="36" Width="35" Margin="0,0,0,0"
          MouseEnter="buttonClear_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="buttonClear_MouseLeave">

            <Path Name="xSVG" Data="M 9.00,9.00
                   C 9.00,9.00 27.00,27.00 27.00,27.00M 27.00,9.00
                   C 27.00,9.00 9.00,27.00 9.00,27.00"
              Stretch="Fill"
              Stroke="White"
              Fill="White"
              Margin="12,12,12,12"
              StrokeThickness="2.5"
              StrokeStartLineCap="Round"
              StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
              MouseEnter="buttonClear_MouseEnter" 
              MouseLeave="buttonClear_MouseLeave"
              />

        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

ClearableTextBoxDictionary.xaml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">


    <Color x:Key="GradientStartColor">#FF577bff</Color>
    <Color x:Key="GradientEndColor">#aa9a57ff</Color>
    <Color x:Key="HoverGradientStartColor">#FF577bff</Color>
    <Color x:Key="HoverGradientEndColor">#FF00fac4</Color>
    <Color x:Key="PressedHoverGradientStartColor">#FF3056D8</Color>
    <Color x:Key="PressedHoverGradientEndColor">#FF00C29A</Color>
    <Color x:Key="PressedGradientStartColor">#FF2C4AB5</Color>
    <Color x:Key="PressedGradientEndColor">#FF009986</Color>


    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
        <Setter Property="RadiusX" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="RadiusY" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Fill">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource GradientStartColor}" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource GradientEndColor}" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].Color" 
                            To="{StaticResource HoverGradientStartColor}" 
                            Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                        <ColorAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].Color" 
                            To="{StaticResource HoverGradientEndColor}" 
                            Duration="0:0:0.5"/>

                        <DoubleAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" 
                            To="1.04" 
                            Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" 
                            To="1.04" 
                            Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].Color" 
                            To="{StaticResource GradientStartColor}" 
                            Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                        <ColorAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].Color" 
                            To="{StaticResource GradientEndColor}" 
                            Duration="0:0:0.5"/>

                        <DoubleAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" 
                            To="1" 
                            Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" 
                            To="1" 
                            Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Light"/>
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" Opacity="0.2" ShadowDepth="5" Color="DarkSlateGray"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,3,0,0"/>
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10" />
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Semibold"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        CornerRadius="0, 10, 10, 0">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#00b38c"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>

I tried creating a storyboard, and then the event trigger apply that storyboard to the rectangle, but I got back an error

A Storyboard tree in a Style cannot specify a TargetName. Remove TargetName

So it seems like it doesn't want to be referring to other components outside of the intended one. The reason why I went down this path is because when the mouse hovers over the text box, it believes that it is no longer over the rectangle.

I would advise you to use Custom Control instead of UserControl. The basic element should be TextBox and the necessary properties should be added to it.

In this case, it would be better to use template's triggers to change the styling depending on the state change.

Thanks, that helped a lot! I ran into another issue with one of the template triggers, where I couldn't remove the default hover style. The trigger I have does work as it changes the colour of the Path attribute, but not the button.
<Trigger SourceName="ClearButton" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">     <Setter TargetName="ClearButtonPath" Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />     <Setter TargetName="ClearButton" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" /> </Trigger>
What makes it odd is that for the False case trigger, it can set the background colour.

Provide the full current code. Without it, it will not be possible to understand the cause of the problem.

Sorry, I'm not used to posting on stack overflow. Here is my Generic.xaml
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WeatherApp.View.Controls">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/WeatherApp;component/Resources/Colours.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/WeatherApp;component/Resources/MainDictionary.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<!-- Default style for ClearableTextBox -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ClearableTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource GradientStartColor}" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource GradientEndColor}" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" Opacity="0.2" ShadowDepth="5" Color="DarkSlateGray"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ClearableTextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <!-- Background Rectangle -->
                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" 
                           RadiusX="10" 
                           RadiusY="10" 
                           Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />

                    <!-- TextBox Part with ScaleTransform to allow resizing -->
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                              Margin="5,0,40,0"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                              HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                            <!-- Default scale -->
                        </ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
                    </ScrollViewer>

                    <!-- Clear Button -->
                    <Button x:Name="ClearButton" 
                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding IsClearButtonVisible}" 
                        Width="35" 
                        Height="35" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                        Margin="0,0,5,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Background="Transparent" 
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Panel.ZIndex="1">
                        <Path x:Name="ClearButtonPath" 
                          Data="M 9.00,9.00 C 9.00,9.00 27.00,27.00 27.00,27.00M 27.00,9.00 C 27.00,9.00 9.00,27.00 9.00,27.00"
                          Stretch="Fill" 
                          Stroke="White" 
                          Margin="9,9"
                          StrokeThickness="3.5"  
                          StrokeStartLineCap="Round" 
                          StrokeEndLineCap="Round"/>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                        <Setter TargetName="ClearButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger SourceName="ClearButton" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ClearButtonPath" Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ClearButton" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger SourceName="ClearButton" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="ClearButtonPath" Property="Stroke" Value="White" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ClearButton" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                                    To="1.04" 
                                    Duration="0:0:0.23"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                                    To="1.04" 
                                    Duration="0:0:0.23"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>

                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                                    To="1.0" 
                                    Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                                    To="1.0" 
                                    Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>

Button when not hovered over
Button when hovered over
I don't have any other button styles conflicting with it. I tried testing it with this change
<Trigger SourceName="ClearButton" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ClearButtonPath" Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ClearButton" Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger SourceName="ClearButton" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="ClearButtonPath" Property="Stroke" Value="White" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ClearButton" Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>

Button with Green background visible
Button with hover background unchanged
and it seems there must be some other overlay, or maybe there could be a conflict with some of the bindings with other components?

Never mind, I fixed this problem, I needed to override the Button control template, so I created a button style with a control template containing the Path, and then I applied this to the style of the button in ClearableTextBox. Thanks for your help!
